# Is it best practice to use the “Collecting Parameter" pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm currently reading Joshua Kerivsky's 'Refactoring To Patterns'. One of the refactoring techniques referred to in the book is based upon Kent Beck's 'Collecting Parameter' pattern.

This pattern is described as something you may need when you are needing to accumulate data, (such as with Java's `StringBuffer`) compared to lots of calls and returns. In the book, he describes a **Collecting Parameter** as *an object that you pass to methods in order to collect info from those methods*.

I cannot find many examples of people talking about this online and it seems to be rarely discussed. I'm wondering how/when is best practice to use a pattern like this, as I don't know if it's the 'done thing' these days. I haven't seen it used in production and I generally don't know if it's an 'old world' programming technique.

I see that we are mutating the object every time we want to accumulate data which, if you look at functional programming principles is generally bad practice. But is it okay in an OOP sense?

Simple example of usage (Java):

FROM:

```
result += "<" + tagName + " " + attributes + ">";
```

TO:

```
private void writeOpenTagTo(StringBuffer result) {
    result.append("<");
    result.append(name);
    result.append(" ");
    result.append(attributes.toString());
    result.append(">");
}
```

Comment: I think this belongs to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. I haven't used this pattern much, but I have done it in the past for very similar examples the one you posted, and rendering things (e.g. a PDF, where I pass a 'PDFWriter' to different widgets). It's usually easier to understand code when functions/methods return a value rather than modify a parameter, but I wouldn't completely discard this approach in some cases. It can be seen as a bit of a variant of the Double Dispatch pattern.